# Generating Matlab Code using Maple

Tags: maple

When exporting Matlab Code from Maple using for example the command `fprintf(FileName, %s, CodeGeneration[Matlab](VariableName, output = string))`  I get the text `cg2=Expression`.

`Expression`  is correctly exported, except that the variable name is not.

I want to write the variable name instead of `cg2` (knowing that $cg_i$ is generated automatically by Maple and the $i=0,1,2,...$) . Can any one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

> CodeGeneration[Matlab](x^2+3, output=string, resultname = y);

"y = x^2 + 3"

Comment: Thanks. You might have to put the 'y' between quotations so the other users can use it.